# how to receive HashMap in Restful webservice?

Tags: rest

I am developing an ecommerce application and I got a problem in one of my rest sevices.
I want to receive a hashmap from a client and I don't know how to proceed?

Could you please help me out?

Thanks,
Anteneh

Comment: What specific problem do you have with returning a `HashMap`? What language are you using (from `HashMap`, I assume Java)? What format is your response (JSON, XML...)? Do you know what you have to do but are having problems with generating the response, or do you not know what format a `HashMap` would have in the format you chose for your webservice? Your question is utterly unanswerable without more details, and preferably some code.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind help Amadan...I am sorry for being not that much interactive. I have actually understood what I have to do and solved the problem. What i did was that I have created a POJO consisting of the hashmap and other attributes then used JSON object as a means of consuming/producing .